# Email-to-Case to recognise IP and associate with a Country

Tags: geolocation, email2case, ip

Is it possible for the Email-to-Case functionality to recognise the Country of the originating Email by IP Address?

When Email-to-Case creates a Case, we would like to automatically update the Country (custom picklist) field based on IP address.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

BR,
Lakis